# Implement SOAP "Gateway" with Apache CXF?

Tags: soap, cxf

I have a service that uses requires SenderVouches authentication, which works fine for CXF-based Java applications. But now we need to integrate an .NET-based application that does not support SenderVouches in it's SOAP/WS-Security Stack.

I looked around a little bit an found this article explaining the underlying theory of the WS-Trust underlying the SenderVouches: https://www.xml.com/pub/a/ws/2003/06/24/ws-trust.html

In there I found this diagram which could be a solution to the problem we're facing, using a SOAP "Gateway". Does Apache CXF has support for implementing the Gateway part?

[image: WS-Trust scenario components]

I searched around, but most results are unrelated to implementing a SOAP Gateway.